# WSDL and XSD List declaration

Tags: c#, xsd, wsdl

Today I have the folowwing xsd declaration that is generated to Array

```
<xs:element name="SubNodes" type="Node" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

How can I do something that will be generated to List<> ?

(Using c#)

**Update:**

I've tried

```
<xs:simpleType name="SubNodes">
                    <xs:list itemType="Node"/>
                </xs:simpleType>
```

but got the error:

> The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:simpleType' element is not
>   supported in this context

Answer (score 0):

What tool are you using to generate the wsdl? I will assume it is visual studio.

In that case when you generate the service reference, click "Advanced" and you should see this screen where you can select the collection type:

[image]

Comment: thanks but still getting the same error:


---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
The document was understood, but it could not be processed.
  - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
  - The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:simpleType' element is not supported in this context.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are doing? It is not clear from your question.

Comment: Thanks @hugu - I have a wsdl file which i'm using in my visual studio c# project. I want the XSD to generate List<Node>, and when I'm adding the simpleType above to the XSD, and than in the visual studio update the service reference - there's an error.

Comment: OK so don't modify the XSD. Just take the one provided by the WSDL and then generate your service reference from it, using the *Collection Type* drop down as indicated by the image in my original answer. When you generate your reference any collection type should be a generic list rather than an array. There are times when this just won't work, but we'll get into that later.

Comment: @hugu - OK, I returned to the old XSD which does not show any errors, but it still generating array instead of List.
(Just to remind)this is the list declaration in the XSD:

<xs:element name="SubNodes" type="Node" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>